# wkhtmltopdf option 'disable-smart-shrinking' doesn't work

Tags: qt, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. wkhtmltopdf.exe --disable-smart-shrinking --print-media-type --page-size A4 --dpi 96 --margin-top 25 --margin-bottom 25 file:///.../debug.html mytest.pdf

What is the expected output? 
I expect to see the non-shrinked content in result pdf-file

What do you see instead?
Shrinked content in the result pdf-file

What version of wkhtmltopdf are you using?
0.11.0 rc2

On what operating system?
Windows 7 64-bit

The problem is a little bit wider. I need to insert page breaks before some divs depending on their height. I wrote the appropriate script. But the thing is in "shrinked world" the coordinates analyzed by the script change and it the result is ugly. So I need to disable shrinking to make it work correctly.

On the other hand the documentation says '--disable-smart-shrinking' is "only available using patched QT". Does my version of 'wkhtmltopdf' implement this stuff? How can I find it out? Should I install QT or even rebuild the wkhtmltopdf?

Comment: is this still a question? with "wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0 final" windows7 64 i solved it (probably ;-)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out "--disable-smart-shrinking is only available using patched QT."

To know which version of wkhtmltopdf you are using, open a terminal and run:

```
wkhtmltopdf -V
```

It should tell you whether you're using the patched version or not. For example:

```
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6.1 (with patched qt)
```

If your version doesn't have the patched qt remove it and get the appropriate version for your system on https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html